# $X=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3;y=|x|\}$ is not diffeomorphic to the $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

**Problem**: *Show that $X=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3;y=|x|\}$ is not diffeomorphic to the $\mathbb{R}^2$.*

I'm trying to show that the set of points (0,0, z) has tangent space with dimension equal to one. But I can not solve it.

Comment: What is your definition of diffeomorphism?

Comment: Differential bijection with differentiable inverse.

Comment: In such case $X$ is diffeomorphic to the plane, and even isometric to it with respect to a natural metric. You only begin to perceive the difference between them relative to the embedding in 3-space.

Comment: They are not diffeomorphic, it is that the set has a "corner" and the plane does not.

Comment: They are homeomorphic, but they are not diffeomorphic.

Comment: I would say that in order to even ask if two spaces are diffeomorphic, they must be given smooth structures ahead of time.  Now, $X$ does *not* inherit a smooth structure from $\mathbb{R}^3$, but any smooth structure you give it will make it diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with its usual smooth structure.

Comment: Graphically you can notice this. The key is to analyze the points where only z is nonzero. What I'm not getting is to come up with the result to prove it.